# similar question about volume of Parallelepiped

Tags: geometry

from the link

```
http://www.naec.ge/images/doc/EXAMS/exams-2011-gat-4-ivlisi-.pdf
```

problem number 76 states that right Parallelepiped  presented on figure  has dimension `length=8cm`  and is divided into 6 equal right Parallelepiped,we are asked to the same question as my previous one or we should find volume  of each,my effort is following i concluded that each one has height =8  length =4 and width=2 but am not sure so  volume is v=a*b*h=8*4*2=64 can you say if i am correct?or not please correct me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. The fact that each of the pieces is $8 \times 4 \times 2$ is clear from the picture.  After you know length, width, and height, volume is trivial to calculate.

Comment: And do well on your National Exam! You have obviously worked hard.